# Hide Navigation Bar like facebook

Tags: swift, webview, ios8, hide, navigationbar

I'm having a little problem... I have a `UIWebViewController` with a `UINavigationBar` predefined because it's one of the managed ViewControllers by a `UINavigationController`. I want to hide this navigationbar (only in this viewcontroller) when I scroll, like the Facebook app does. (The navigation bar slides up at the sam speed that the user is scrolling, the elements in it fade away, the color of the navigationbar stays visible behind the statusbar, and when you scroll up again the navigationbar appears again, also with the same speed as the user is scrolling.) This is maybe much to ask, but I'm new to programming and have no idea how to start this... Please help?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score -1):

set your NavigationController to hidesBarOnSwipe = true

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
    navController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
}
```

Comment: But this way it doesn't look like it does in the Facebook app, does it?

Comment: Tried it, it hides the navbar indeed, but not when the user is scrolling slowly... I want it to look like Facebook for a 100%. Do you know how to do that? Thanks for answering (and sorry for the bad english)

Comment: This component could fullfill your requirements https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar

Comment: Already found that on the internet, but because I'm new to developping, I don't understand this.. I have no idea what I have to use :( Can you please provide me that? That would be very kind of you!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The documentation on https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar provide steps for installation, setup & sample code that explains it better than I could do in a comment section.

I'd recommend to create (new) specific questions on the road of trying to get TLYShyNavBar up and running